# Fetching documents from DocumentDb using continuation token

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a DocumentDb database with a collection containing 37 documents with each around 150Kb each, now I use the following code snippet to fetch the documents using paging

```
    var options = new FeedOptions
    {
        MaxItemCount = 100
    };

    var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collection, options).AsDocumentQuery();

    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var result = query.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>().Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Quota Usage: {0}", result.CurrentResourceQuotaUsage);
        Console.WriteLine("Continuation Token: {0}", result.ResponseContinuation ?? "null");
        var list = result.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Document Count: {0}", list.Count);
    }
```

The results I get are strange though

```
Quota Usage: documentSize=4;documentsSize=4386;documentsCount=37;collectionSize= 4395; 

Continuation Token: null 

Document Count: 36
```

I am not getting the last document ever as the continuation token becomes null after fetching 36 documents while document count does show up as 37. I am struggling to understand this behaviour and is there a way I can make this work to return all the documents.

Comment: can you check how many documents there really is by using cosmos db explorer?

Comment: there are 37 documents in total.

Comment: does the query "select * from root" in cosmos db explorer return you all 37 docs?.. maybe that one doc missing in index or missing partition key ?

Comment: Yes, if I use sql query it does return me 37 docs. another interesting thing is that if I set MaxItemCount in FeedOptions above to 10, it fetches all 37 in 4 iterations. So I am kind of confused what is the reason it behaves differently. Just to add more details the collection RU/s is 400 and documents are created programatically and I do not set any row/partition key as data is simply a json and I can filter using the ID value of the document.

Comment: i know that in some cases request can return less than `MaxItemCount` property if size of response is greater than max allowed by cosmos db client. But, in this case you would receive a continuation token in a response to first query. Please, post here, if u find the reason of such behavior..

Comment: @ashish1238 Have you catch the missing document? Is it the last one? Have you tried to reproduce this behavior with more documents or less documents? Or reproduce it in a new collection? Please try further tests to get more clues.